# Remove everything after a changing string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, cut

I'm having some trouble with the following problem;

As input, I get a few lines of paths to files as follows:

```
root/child/abc/somefile.txt
root/child/def/123/somefile.txt
root/child/ghijklm/somefile.txt
```

The `root/child` piece is always in the path, everything after can differ.

I would like to remove everything after the grandchild folder. So the output would be:

```
root/child/abc/
root/child/def/
root/child/ghijklm/
```

I've tried the following:

```
sed 's/\/child\/.*/\/child\/.*/'
```

But of course that would just give the following output:

```
root/child/.*
root/child/.*
root/child/.*
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With GNU awk: `awk '{NF=3; NF++}1' FS=/ OFS=/ file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with cut:

```
cut -d\/ -f1,2,3 file
```

Comment: Or: `cut -d / -f 1-3 file`

Answer (score 2):

***With `awk`:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/root\/child\/[^/]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/root\/child\/[^/]*/){    ##Using match function to match root/child/... till next / in current line.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  ##printig substring from RSTART to till RLENGTH.
}
' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***With `sed`:***

```
sed 's/.*\(root\/child\/[^/]*\).*/\1/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s substitution method to match `root/child/ till next occurrence of /` and saving it into temp buffer(back reference method) and substituting whole line with only matched back referenced value.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(([^/]*[/]){3}).*/\1/' file
```

Delete everything after the third group of non-forward-slashes/slash.

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

```sh
sed 's%\(/child/[^/]*\)/.*%\1%'
```

The regex `[^/]*` matches as many characters as possible which are not a slash; then we replace the entire match with just the part we captured in parentheses, effectively trimming off the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**With Perl:**

```
perl -pe 's{ ^ ( ( [^/]+ / ){3} ) .* $ }{$1}x' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

The regex uses this modifier:
`x` : Disregard whitespace and comments, for readability.

The substitution statement, explained:
`^` : beginning of the line.
`$` : end of the line.
`[^/]+ /` : one or more characters that are not slashes (`/`), followed by a slash.
`( [^/]+ / ){3}` : one or more non-slash characters, followed by a slash, repeated exactly 3 times.
`( ( [^/]+ / ){3} )` : the above, with parenthesis to capture the matched part into the first capture variable, `$1`, to be used later in the substitution. Capture groups are counted left to right.
`.*` : zero or more occurrences of any character.
`s{THIS}{THAT}` : replace `THIS` with `THAT`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)